# How to run multiple other bash commands in a line after the first failed

Tags: command-line, bash

When some command (from inside a bash script) fails, an error message shall be issued and then the script shall be exited.

Lets just show the example (with the last command wrapped into an echo string for easier testing):

```
$ which which || echo "failed"; echo "exit 1"
/usr/bin/which
exit 1
$ which which1 || echo "failed"; echo "exit 1"
failed
exit 1
```

As you can see the example does /exit/ in any case. Instead it only should exit for the second case. How to solve that to achieve the desired behavior? I suppose there are some options built into bash for grouping the command items #2 and #3...

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a subshell, as you show in [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1203181/85695):

```
which which1 || ( echo "failed"; echo "exit 1" )
```

or group the commands without starting a separate subshell:

```
which which1 || { echo "failed"; echo "exit 1"; }
```

<sub>Note: for more details on `{ }` vs `( )`, see the "Compound Commands" and "COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT" sections of `man bash`.</sub>

Or, you can do something like this which lets you build more complex handlers:

```
#!/bin/bash

which "$1"

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Failed: Exited with $?"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Worked!"
fi
```

You could also write this as a function:

```
#!/bin/bash
runme(){
  "$@"
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Failed: Exited with $?"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "Worked!"
  fi
}

runme which which1
```

Or, more simply if you don't need the exit status to be shown:

```
#!/bin/bash
runme(){
  if "$@"; then
    echo "Worked"
  else
    echo "Failed!"
    exit 1
  fi
}

runme which which
```

Comment: sure - multi line solutions will work. but they will bloat the scripting. the functional approach works nice if scripted. for a shell one-liner the initial solution just is it.

Answer (score 1):

This evidently solves it using curly braces (=grouping the commands; the trailing semicolon is obligatory):

```
$ which which || { echo "failed"; echo "exit 1"; }
/usr/bin/which
$ which which1 || { echo "failed"; echo "exit 1"; }
failed
exit 1
```

This evidently solves it using round braces (=invoking a sub shell; not recommended):

```
$ which which || ( echo "failed"; echo "exit 1" )
/usr/bin/which
$ which which1 || ( echo "failed"; echo "exit 1" )
failed
exit 1
```

Grouping of commands in bash is done using curly or round braces with slight differences under the hood that might increase execution duration for the second case and requiring a slightly more precise coding syntax for the first case.

Comment: i would vote for the option that steeldriver proposed. putting it into the text in a few moments.